# How to model a Listing Database?

Tags: database, models

I have a quick question. Currently I'm learning Ruby On Rails and I'm making progress! Slowly, but progress nonetheless.

How would you model a product/ listing database which a user can create.

For example would it be:

Listing

- Listing_Id
- User_Id
- Description
- Price

Or would it be a Listing, which is associated with various models. Such as Price Model, Location Model etc.

When would I use models in relation to a listing such as above?

Or am I looking at this the completely wrong way.
Thanks

Comment: When is it advantageous to use additional models vs  storing it all in in the one model? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If user can create many products then association would be:

User has_many products

So there are two models User and Product.

Add user_id under Product table.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation . Suppose

- if your product price is fixed then you would try your above schema.
- If your product price can changeable then you need a different table (**One to many relation**) for product price table . So look like id , price , product_id , date.
- If your product have location then you need **Many to Many** relation. for example table look like -id , product_id , location_id.